# Notificaciones push firebase no funciona ,sdk java firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notificaciones, fcm, firebase-messaging

Cuando corro mi código en la clase main funciona correctamente ,pero en el backend este código no funciona.

No hay excepciones ,no muestra ningún error.

Puse impresiones para ver que pasaba ,pero nunca muestra la impresión 3.
java version : 1.8 server : glassfish 5

El código corre en la clase main pero no en el backend, pensé que sucedía esto porque estaba en mi maquina local(localhost),pero subí el código al servidor y pasa lo mismo, el código no corre y no muestra errores

Dependencia de maven

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
         <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
         <version>6.4.0</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                 <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                 <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
     </dependency>
```

importsgenerados

> import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp; import
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.AndroidConfig; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.AndroidNotification; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.ApnsConfig; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.Aps; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.TopicManagementResponse; import
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.WebpushConfig;

Código que funciona en el main

```
try {
        System.out.println("1");

FileInputStream serviceAccount= new FileInputStream("/serviceAccountKey.json");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setServiceAccountId("projectId")
                .setProjectId("projectId")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        System.out.println("2");

        com.google.firebase.messaging.Message message = 
            com.google.firebase.messaging.Message.builder()
                .putData("tipo", "cargueTareasFinalizado")
                .putData("nombreAmigo", "DARIOOO")
                .putData("pagina", "DARIOOO")
                .setToken(token)
                .setNotification(new Notification(
                        "Dario up 1.43% on the day",
                        "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 
                         1.43% on the day."))
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setTtl(3600 * 1000)
                        .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder()
                                .setTitle("titulo android")
                                .setBody("body android")
                                .setIcon("icon_color")
                                .setColor("#247c2e")
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                        .setAps(Aps.builder()
                                .setBadge(0)
                                .build())
                        .putCustomData("titulo", "tiiiiiiii")
                        .putCustomData("body", "bodddd")
                        .putCustomData("tipo", "cargueTareasFinalizado")
                        .build())
                .setWebpushConfig(WebpushConfig.builder()
                        .putData("titulo", "Tiiiiii")
                        .putData("body", "bodddy")
                        .putData("icon", "\"images/favicon.png\"")
                        .build())
                .build();

       System.out.println("3");

        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Comment: buenas tardes, el desarrollo es en android ? , si son notificaciones push deberias seguir esta doc de android https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419   ya que las podes mandar desde la consola de firebase

Comment: La notificación es para una app híbrida hecha con cordova ,para ios ,web y android ,las notificaciones si las envio desde la consola de firebase llegan perfectamente,y actualmente estoy enviándolas usando el api de firebase (http request), pero quiero implementar el sdk de java y sucede que el código funciona en la clase main pero no en el backend (proyecto ya corriendo)